# htmlUnit - Is it possible to execute only specific JS functions?

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

I have an issue - I'm trying to scrape a Cinema webpage, 
--->  https://cinemaxx.dk/koebenhavn

I need to get data regarding how many seats that is reserved/sold, I need to extract the last snapshot.

The seats that are reserved/sold is shown on the picture as a red square:

[image]

Basiclly, my logic is this.

1. I scrape the contact using htmlUnit.
2. I set htmlUnit to execute all JS.
3. extract the (reservedSeats BASE64 String).
4. Convert the BASE64 string to image.
5. Then my program analyse the image, and count how many seats that is reserved / sold.

   - My issue is:

As I need the last snapshot of the picture, - cause that is the picture that gives the correct data related to how many seats that is reserved / sold. - I start scraping the website 3 min before the movie start,... and untill input == null.

I do this by looping my scrape method - But the ciname server automatic reserve 2 seats at each request (and hold them for 10 minutes). - So I end up reserving all the seats in the whle cinema... (you can see an example on the 2 reserved seats (blue squares) on the picture above)).

I found the JS method in the HTML that reserved the 2 seats at request - Now I would like htmlUnit to execute all JS exect this one JS method that reserves theese 2 seats by HTTP request.

- I hope it gives sense, all above.
- Is there someone out there that maybe can lead me in the right direction ?, or maybe had similar issue?.

```
public void scraper(String url) {

    final String URL = url;

    //Initialize Ghost Browser (FireFox_60):
    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_60)) {

        //Configure Ghost Browser:
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);

        //Load Url & Configure Ghost Browser:
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(URL);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(3000);


        //Spider JS PATH to BASE64 data:
        final HtmlElement seatPictureRaw = page.querySelector
                ("body > div.page.page--booking.ng-scope > div.relative > div.inner__container.inner__container--content " +
                        "> div.seatselect > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.seatselect__image > img");

        //Terminate Current web session:
        webClient.getCurrentWindow().getJobManager().removeAllJobs();
        webClient.close();


        //Process the raw BASE64 Data - Extract clean BASE64 String:
        String rawBASE64Data = String.valueOf(seatPictureRaw);
        String[] arrOfStr = rawBASE64Data.split("(?<=> 0\") ");
        String cleanedUpBASE64Data = arrOfStr[1];
        String cleanedUpBASE64Data1 = cleanedUpBASE64Data.replace("src=\"data:image/gif;base64,", "");
        String cleanedUpBASE64Data2 = cleanedUpBASE64Data1.replace("\">]", "");
        //System.out.println(cleanedUpBASE64Data2);


        //Decode BASE64 Rawdata to Image:
        final byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cleanedUpBASE64Data2);
        System.out.println("Numbers Of Caracters in BASE64 String: " + decodedBytes.length);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes));

        //Forward image for PictureAnalyzer Class...
        final PictureAnalyzer pictureAnalyzer = new PictureAnalyzer();
        pictureAnalyzer.analyzePixels(image);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that a Flash app ..?

Comment: @Teemu - erhh what do you exactly mean ?. the site ?

Comment: you need javascript enabled to get the graphic - right?

Comment: Please cleanup you code at first; it makes sense to configure the client before doing anything else - move all the  webClient.getOptions() statements to the top

Comment: usually webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController()); is not required do you really need this?

Comment: Will have a deeper look at your question later on

Comment: @RBRi - In this case I do need to load javascript, as the picture I need to scrape is loading after execution of a specific JS.

*Code have been cleaned up, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to intercept&modify the server responses and replace the function call with something else.

- replace only the function name (this is uggly because it will generate a js exceptions at runtime) or
- remove the function call from the source or
- replace the function body with {} or
- ....

See http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#HowToModifyRequestOrResponse for more

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by "noop" ?.